# Kubuntu upgrade in Ubuntu Studio environment

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I run Ubuntu Studio session 13.10 on Kubuntu. It got upgraded automatically to XFCE. I want to update my Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred method:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

You can also use the update-manager (all editions):

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
sudo update-manager -d
```

You can also use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```